# How to add "rel=nofollow" to ALL external links?

Tags: navigation

How to add "rel=nofollow" attribute to ALL external links....in Drupal 7?

So far I can find only with different filters and what not....

Before I was working with Joomla - I had a single plugin which was once set up - and wrapped ALL, completely all external links, wherever they would be - in Menus, articles, modules, social buttons, advertisements, etc....

I just cannot understand why would I need some Filter - the only Filtering option should be - it is an External link...

If I would know all external URL some scripts or users may add to my site - it would be great. But my experience shows - external URLs are almost always added secretly without me being aware of it; but it still should have "rel=nofollow"..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this module : [Noindex External Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/noindex_external_links#english)

Module let's you take full control of external links indexing. Pages could also pass HTML-validation.

> **Features**
>
> Two methods of indexing control:
>
> - Wrap links with NOINDEX tag. NOINDEX tag is used to deny indexing part of page. Only Yandex and Rambler considers this tag but Google
>     and others doesn't. There is also an attribute NOINDEX in meta-tag
>     Robots.
> - Add attribute rel="nofollow" to links. This link's attribute has no effect on indexing. Only Google really do not follow this links but
>     others do. Attribute is used to say to search engine that links no
>     longer constitute a "vote" in the PageRank system.

Comment: I have seen that, but I couldn't make it to work...may be it's because I'm on WAMP?

Comment: What isn't working ? Any error or something ?

Comment: no error, nothing at all, didn't show up in code; but I have heard it's working for some people....I don't know why, so my assumption was - whether it depends on some filters again, whether it's because on WAMP...

Comment: Maybe you have to go to your text format. It worked for me after that. check : https://www.reinisfischer.com/how-no-follow-external-links-still-do-follow-internal-links-drupal-7